# Conversor de divisas en Batch Script

Tags: windows, cmd, batch

Estoy tratando de crear en batch script un conversor de divisas.

El codigo fuente que tengo es este:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
title Conversor multidivisas de los paises que tienen el euro:
rem Indicando las cantidades de las divisas convertidas:
set a[0]=6.55957
set a[1]=166.386
set a[2]=13.7603
set a[3]=1.95583
set a[4]=40.3399
set a[5]=110.265
set a[6]=0.585274
set a[7]=1.95583
set a[8]=15.6466
set a[9]=166.386
set a[10]=5.94573
set a[11]=6.55957
set a[12]=340.75
set a[13]=0.787564
set a[14]=1936.27
set a[15]=491.96775
set a[16]=3.4528
set a[17]=40.3399
set a[18]=0.702804
set a[19]=6.55957
set a[20]=1.95583
set a[21]=0.4293
set a[22]=2.20371
set a[23]=200.482
set a[24]=239.64
set a[25]=30.126
set a[26]=1936.27
set a[27]=1936.27
set a[28]=655.957
set a[29]=655.957
set a[30]=119.3317
rem Indicando el nombre de las divisas convertidas:
set b[0]=Franco Andorrano
set b[1]=Peseta Andorrana
set b[2]=Chelin Austriaco
set b[3]=Marco Bosnio-Herzegovino
set b[4]=Franco Belga
set b[5]=Escudo Caboverdiano
set b[6]=Libra Chipriota
set b[7]=Marco Aleman
set b[8]=Corona Estonia
set b[9]=Peseta Espanyola
set b[10]=Marco Finlandes
set b[11]=Franco Frances
set b[12]=Dracma Griega
set b[13]=Libra Irlandesa
set b[14]=Lira Italiana
set b[15]=Franco Comorense
set b[16]=Litas Lituana
set b[17]=Franco Luxemburgues
set b[18]=Lats Leton
set b[19]=Franco Monegasco
set b[20]=Denar Macedonio
set b[21]=Lira Maltesa
set b[22]=Florin Neerlandes
set b[23]=Escudo Portugues
set b[24]=Tolar Esloveno
set b[25]=Corona Eslovaca
set b[26]=Lira Sanmarinense
set b[27]=Lira Vaticana
set b[28]=Franco CFA de Africa Central
set b[29]=Franco CFA de Africa Occidental
set b[30]=Franco CFP Polinesia Francesa
rem Mostrando el nombre de las divisas:
for /l %%n in (0,1,30) do ( 
echo !b[%%n]! 
)
rem Introduciendo la cantidad a convertir:
set /p "cantidad=Cuanta cantidad quieres convertir? "
rem El nombre de la divisa original:
set /p "divisainicial=Como se llama la divisa inicial? "
rem El nombre de la divisa final:
set /p "divisafinal=Como se llama la divisa final? "
rem Guardando en una variable el numero del array de la divisa inicial:
for /l %%n in (0,1,30) do ( 
if "!b[%%n]!"=="%divisainicial%" (
    set /a "contadorinicial=%%n"
)
)
rem Guardando en una variable el numero del array de la divisa final:
for /l %%n in (0,1,30) do ( 
if "!b[%%n]!"=="%divisafinal%" (
    set /a "contadorinicial=%%n"
)
)
rem Convirtiendolo al euro:
set /a "euros=%cantidad%/!a[%contadorinicial%]!"
rem Convirtiendolo a la nueva divisa:
set /a "nuevadivisa=%euros%*!a[%contadorfinal%]!"
echo %cantidad% %divisainicial% equivale a %nuevadivisa% %divisafinal%
pause
exit
```

El problema lo he llegado a ver con dos mensajes que me aparecen que son estos mas el mensaje final, en el que me aparece casi todo el mensaje:

***Falta el operador.***
***Falta un operando.***
***200 Peseta Espanyola equivale a  Franco Frances*** (en este caso, no me muestra la cantidad convertida)

Una indicacion con el codigo fuente. La parte de donde tengo las divisas, lo tengo puesto con decimales (por lo general, sabemos que los decimales en programacion se indican con puntos)